# Why make a quicker retry will improve the success rate in my case

Tags: java

I'm using guava-retrying to do some retries, when I set the withWaitStrategy() to 5 seconds, it failed sometimes, but if I change withWaitStrategy() to 1 second, the success rate is 100%, why does it happened? can anyone help me out.

```
        Callable<Boolean> callable = () -> {
            itemBeforeUpdate.set(table.getItem(getActionHashKeyField(), hashKeyValue, getActionRangeKeyField(), rangeKeyValue));

            return itemBeforeUpdate.get().asMap().get(testPayloadName).equals(itemBeforeUpdate.get().asMap().get(attributeName));
        };

        Retryer<Boolean> retryer = RetryerBuilder.<Boolean>newBuilder()
                .withWaitStrategy(WaitStrategies.fixedWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .withStopStrategy(StopStrategies.stopAfterDelay(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .withAttemptTimeLimiter(AttemptTimeLimiters.fixedTimeLimit(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .retryIfResult(BooleanUtils::isFalse)
                .build();

            retryer.call(callable);Callable<Boolean> callable = () -> {
            itemBeforeUpdate.set(table.getItem(getActionHashKeyField(), hashKeyValue, getActionRangeKeyField(), rangeKeyValue));

            return itemBeforeUpdate.get().asMap().get(testPayloadName).equals(itemBeforeUpdate.get().asMap().get(attributeName));
        };


            retryer.call(callable);
```

Comment: I'm removing the [tag:guava] tag because despite the name, guava-retrying is not part of Guava.